# Infinite linear subgroups characteristic $p$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL(n,F)$ where $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$. Suppose $g^m = 1$ for every element $g \in G$ such that $ p \not| m$. Then can the group $G$ be infinite?

The only two solutions I can come up with is where you take $F = \overline{F_p}$ and then take matrix groups with roots of 1 on the diagonal, however the size of these groups is a function of the exponent $m$ which is fixed. The other idea is some quotiented polynomial ring $F_p(x,y)/(f(x,y))$ for some polynomial $f(x,y)$ so that the quotient kills terms by raising to a power that $p$ does not divide. However I feel that $G$ must be finite. Can someone possibly confirm and suggest a method of proof?

Thanks.

Comment: I find the phrasing of your second sentence confusing. Do you mean there exists a natural number $m$ that is not divisible by $p$, such that $g^m=1$ for all $g\in G$?

Comment: Or more precisely. you have an undefined  symbol $m$ in the question.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus The post has been rolled back.  To the original poster:  **Do not deface your question**, especially after others have taken their time to answer it.  Such self-vandalism is explicitly discouraged and against site policy.  If you make an error in your post, you are free to edit it, but deleting the entire question is inappropriate.

Comment: [How do I disassociate a question with my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285385/how-do-i-disassociate-a-question-with-my-account)

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that the group $G$ has fixed finite exponent $e$, then we have
$|G|\le e^{n^3}$, see [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869376901563/1-s2.0-0021869376901563-main.pdf?_tid=052ecfe2-bfef-11e6-bf9c-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1481494578_b5afd1b90777e3b52c96783110030497), after Hypothesis $A$, with the reference to Dixon's book $[3]$. In characteristic zero, Burnside's Theorem gives this bound, too.